# Что может помешать установке веб-окружения битрикса?

Tags: php, битрикс

При установке Битрикса, не корректно устанавливается Веб-окружение. Какие стандартные программы винды могут блокировать установку Веб окружения?

Comment: какая ошибка?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error, в процессах нет программах отвечающих за работу веб сервера. Такое ощущение, что при установке какая то программа блокирует 80 порт, из за этого установка не проходит.

Comment: @damasco, Skype или TeamViewer

Comment: вам уже написали = что 80 паорт любиь забирать скайп - уберите у него 80 порт в настройках

Comment: у меня нет скайпа.

Comment: Нет ни того, ни другого.

Comment: глядя на заголовок вопроса, так и захотелось написать ответ: "Здравый смысл" ;))))

Comment: Кажется, что, раз ты получаешь ошибку от веб-сервера (а кто же еще возвращает 500 ошибку с развернутым ответом? Скайп, что ли?), значит, все с ним нормально. Ищи ошибку именно в настройках сервера. Может, где-то права доступа директорий нужно поправить. А еще сам битрикс может выкидывать этот ответ – он такой. А еще битрикс составляет массивный htaccess – посмотри в него, может, он туда чего-то лишнего написал.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете попытаться посмотреть кто висит на 80 порту из консоли:

```
netstat -a -t -b
```

Если список излишне велик то можете вывод перенаправить в текстовый файл для анализа

```
netstat -a -t -b > netinfo.txt
```

или сразу попытаться отфильтровать

```
netstat -a -t -b | findstr :80
```